# How to make logic operations with 2d array java?

Tags: java, arrays, javafx

I'm working on a JavaFX program that reads in the data file and starts to  process the columns.

So far I'm reading in the file and then I loop through each column and I construct a 2d array.

That way I can calculate mean and median values. 
But I would like to know how can I make logical operations with these columns in java?

Let's say we have a file which contains the following columns and rows and for this example, let's make an assumption that elements in the file are separated with commas (but they might not be).

```
V1,V2,V3,V4
 1, 4, 1, 4
 2, 5, 2, 4
 3, 2, 3, 5
 4, 3, 4, 2
```

Now, the user wants to find all the rows that meet the following:

```
V1 > 2 AND V2 < 3 OR V3 < 4
```

In this case, the result would be 1st, 2nd and 3rd row, which I need to save into the file, after program has finished with the file.

```
V1,V2,V3,V4
 1, 4, 1, 4
 2, 4, 2, 5
 3, 2, 3, 5
```

Any kind of help is welcome!

Comment: thanks for the downvote too for no reason

Comment: This question seems to be too broad for this forum. What part are you actually stuck with here? How is the user specifying the filter criterion for the data?

Comment: I'm stuck with the parsing part where user selects the columns from which she would like to get the data and program prints out all the rows that meet the criterias. As in example, user wants to find all the rows which meet the criteria. In this case V1 > 2 & V2 < 3 v V3 < 4. 
User can make AND/OR operations on the columns.

Answer (score 1):

This question is really far too broad for this forum, but I would approach this by creating a small object model for the criteria by which you're filtering data. So something like:

```
public interface Criterion {

    public boolean matches(Map<String, Integer> data) ;

}
```

with

```
public class Inequality implements Criterion {

    public enum Operation { LESS_THAN, GREATER_THAN }

    private final Operation operation ;

    private final String variable ;

    private final int value ;

    public Criterion(Operation op, String variable, int value) {
        this.op = op ;
        this.variable = variable ;
        this.value = value ;
    }

    @Override
    public  boolean matches(Map<String, Integer> data) {
        if (! data.containsKey(variable) ) {
            return false ; // or throw exception...
        }
        int dataValue = data.get(variable);
        switch (operation) {
            case LESS_THAN: return dataValue < value ;
            case GREATER_THAN: return dataValue > value ;
            default: // throw exception ...
        }
    }
}
```

Then classes to combine these:

```
public class And implements Criterion {
    private Criterion left ;
    private Criterion right ;

    public And(Criterion left, Criterion right) {
        this.left = left ;
        this.right = right ;
    }

    @Override
    public void matches(Map<String, Integer> data)  {
        return left.matches(data) && right.matches(data);
    }
}
```

and similarly for `Or`.

Now, given your description of the UI, it should be pretty straightforward to create a `Criterion` object representing the state of the UI. Then just pass each row of the table (represented as a map from variable names to values) through the `Criterion`'s `matches` method, and the ones that return true are the ones matching the filter.

Comment: This helped me a lot! Thank you! I modified a bit and added more operands. 
Using a Map made things a bit easier. But is it good practice to store file data to map? At the moment I use `Map<String, List<String>>` where column values are stored into List and can easily access via keys (as headers).

Answer (score 0):

Just read the `file` in an `array` like you said and `iterate` through the `array` and check the given criteria

Comment: and how do you manage when there is a operation like V1 & (V2 v V3) ?

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use some parser support, for instance [SpEL](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html)
You could write something like:

```
 exp = parser.parseExpression("v[0] > 2 AND v[1] < 3 OR v[2] < 4");
 System.out.println(exp.getValue(v,Boolean.class));
```

Where v is one line of your 2d array, with index starting from 0.

Comment: But you could also build a GUI that allowed the user to build expressions that didn't really need to be parsed...

Comment: At the moment it works like this: 
Program reads in the file. From that file, user will get headers, e.g column names she can work with. 
Then, to filter the columns,  user can select column name she wants to work with, select > or < and enter the column value. 
Then there is a button to add more expressions and operations the same way. She can make only and/or operations and as many as she like.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick method you can use.

> Your comparison is strange though. `V1 > 2 AND V2 < 3 OR V3 < 4`

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // TODO code application logic here
    String[] linesFromFile = {"1, 4, 1, 4",               
                              "2, 5, 2, 4",
                              "3, 2, 3, 5",
                              "4, 3, 4, 2"};

    List<String> saveTrueDataHere = new ArrayList();

    for(int i = 0; i < linesFromFile.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(linesFromFile[i] + ": " + compareItemsInLine(linesFromFile[i]));
        if(compareItemsInLine(linesFromFile[i]))
        {
            saveTrueDataHere.add(linesFromFile[i]);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Number of true items saved: " + saveTrueDataHere.size());
    //Print the items that returned true.
    for(String item : saveTrueDataHere)
    {
        System.out.println(item);
    }
}  

static boolean compareItemsInLine(String line)
{
    String items[] = line.split(", ");

    //                         v1                                v2                                 v3
    return Integer.parseInt(items[0]) > 2 && Integer.parseInt(items[1]) < 3 || Integer.parseInt(items[2]) < 4;
}
```

Comment: Ill give it a try. 
V1, V2, etc are just default column names. The point is to, for example, find Height > 150 OR Width < 100. Where V1 = Height and V2 = Width. 
Thanks, Ill give a try